# Clarification of Notion of a "Good Approximation"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives, linear-approximation

My textbook says the following:

> $$\lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)}{x - x_0} = 0$$
>
> Thus, the tangent line $l$ through $(x_0, f(x_0))$ with slope $f'(x_0)$ is close to $f$ in the sense that the difference between $f(x)$ and $l(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)$, the equation of the tangent line, goes to zero even when divided by $x - x_0$ as $x$ goes to $x_0$. This is the notion of a "good approximation that we will adapt to functions of several variables, with the tangent line replaced by the tangent plane.

I'm finding it difficult to understand how this notion of "good approximation" makes logical sense, given logical reasoning and all of the other mathematics I've learned. For $\dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)}{x - x_0}$, as $x \to x_0$, we have that the numerator and denominator are approaching $0$ at the same rate -- after all, there are no exponents to indicate that one is approaching $0$ quicker than the other. Given this, we would usually say that $\lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)}{x - x_0} = \dfrac{0}{0}$, which is an indeterminate form. In order to have that $\lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)}{x - x_0} = 0$, we would require that the numerator approach $0$ quicker than the denominator, which, as I said, there is no indication of.

So can someone please clarify this notion of "good approximation" and explain why it makes mathematical sense? I'm also wondering if this is just a crude/"hand-wavey" way of explaining the notion of "good approximation", since, as I said, it doesn't seem very sensible, and a more sensible and rigorous way would use epsilon-delta notions? If anyone has a better mathematical explanation of the notion of "good approximation" feel free to share.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: "the numerator and denominator are approaching 0 at the same rate -- after all, there are no exponents to indicate that one is approaching 0 quicker than the other." Careful -- you can't just conclude that. For example, $1-\cos x$ approaches 0 faster than $x$ does, even though "there are no exponents".

Comment: A picture may help: http://www.phengkimving.com/calc_of_one_real_var/08_app_of_the_der_part_2/08_03_tan_line_approx.htm

Comment: Try expanding the fraction inside the limit as $\lim_{x \to x_0} \left(\dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} - \dfrac{f'(x_0)(x - x_0)}{x - x_0}\right).$ Now can you see why it has to be zero, as long as $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: @Rahul Ahh, yes, you make a good point about the exponents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that in general the numerator need not approach zero faster than the denominator.

But the point here is that **IF** the numerator does approach zero faster than the denominator , **THEN** we say that $f(x_0) + f'(x_0)\, (x-x_0)$ is a good approximation to $f(x)$ as $x \to x_0$.

There is no hand-waving at all involved here. This is the **definition** of what the phrase “good approximation” means in this context, and it's all based on the $\epsilon$ & $\delta$ stuff built into the rigorous definition of the concept of **limit**.

Comment: Perhaps it is more accurate to say that for an arbitrary fraction of the form $\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)-m\cdot(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}$, the numerator need not approach zero faster than the denominator? In the case $m=f'(x_0)$, the numerator *does* always approach zero faster than the denominator for any differentiable $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Hans. I'm wondering what about the numerator indicates that it approaches zero faster than the denominator?

Comment: @ThePointer: the indication comes not by looking at numerator but rather from the fact that the limit in question is $0$. Why is the limit $0$? That's because of definition of derivative.

Comment: @ThePointer: by definition $f(x) $ tends to $0$ as $x\to a$ *faster than* $g(x) $ does so if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =0=\lim_{x\to a} g(x) $ and $\lim\limits _{x\to a} \dfrac{f(x)} {g(x)} =0$ so that there is no other meaning or indication of *faster than* other than this limit being $0$. The source of your confusion is that you think there is some other meaning of *faster than* in this context. Consider examples like $f(x) =x^2,g(x)=x$ in this definition and convince yourself

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ohhh, I think I see what it's saying now: **IF** we have the case that $$\lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)}{x - x_0} = 0,$$ **then** what we have done is define, implicitly, that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0) \to 0$ faster than $\lim_{x \to x_0} x - x_0 \to 0$; after all, if we have defined that $\lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)}{x - x_0} = 0$, then this can only be true if $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0) \to 0$ faster than $\lim_{x \to x_0} x - x_0 \to 0$. So [...]

Comment: [...] we have essentially made it true by definition.

Comment: @Rahul: Ah, yes, you're right. Good point. But of course in the case of several variables, which the quoted passage seems to be leading up to, it's a bit more complicated; even though $f'_x(x_0,y_0)$ and $f'_y(x_0,y_0)$ exist, it need not be the case that $\bigl( f(x,y) - f'_x(x_0,y_0) \, (x-x_0) - f'_y(x_0,y_0) \, (y-y_0) \bigr) / \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 - (y-y_0)^2}$ tends to zero as $(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: @ThePointer: glad to know that you understood what I mentioned in comments. +1 for this answer BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Taylor series for $f$ expanded around $x_0$, which gives $$f(x) \approx f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)+\frac 12(x-x_0)^2f''(x_0)+\ldots$$
When $x$ is close to $x_0$ the factor $(x-x_0)$ is small, so as long as the derivatives do not get too large the terms in the expansion will decrease.  You can cut off the sum when the terms get small enough.  As an example, let $f(x)=e^x, x_0=1$, were we know all the derivatives are $1$ as well.  If we want $f(1.01)$ we would write 
$$f(1.01) \approx e+0.01e+\frac 12\cdot 0.01^2e+\ldots$$
Each successive term in the series decreases by a factor larger than $100$ so it is reasonable to ignore all the terms after the first two.  We say that the tangent line is a first order approximation because close to $x_0$ the error of the approximation is proportional to $(x-x_0)^2$, or quadratic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ross. This answer focuses more-so on the numerical aspect of what makes a good approximation from a practical perspective. However, my question is concerned with the analytical aspect of the mathematical notion of a "good approximation" -- especially as it pertains to $\lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x - x_0)}{x - x_0} = 0$

Comment: Whatever is a "good" approximation depends on the context it's used in. In calculus courses we use approximation as an appeal to intuition ("this is *close* to that, and gets closer and closer as we do whatever infinitely many times" or something) - the entire notion of this is formalized much more rigorously in a real analysis class if you ever take one in college. Of course, not everyone needs to into such deep detail to be able to use calculus, you know? So in that sense appealing to intuition tends to be more prudent, and those who are math majors get the details filled in later.